# Running a 'git pull' from EXEC in PHP

Tags: php, windows, git, xampp, exec

I'm trying to run a pull request from git using PHP's `exec` on windows running `XAmpp`. When running the script below with `exec` or `system` and try to access the file the page just never stops loading. I've check the file permissions of the directory and they're all 0777. & running `git status` runs fine. Not sure what the problem is.

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(15);
exec('git pull origin master', $o);
echo implode("\n", $o);
?>
```

Update there isn't a password on the account:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs>git pull origin master
From github.com:************
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.

C:\xampp\htdocs>
```

Running from terminal i get:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs>php -f update.php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ming: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC6
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC9
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: ming: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC6
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC9
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
From github.com:*********
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
C:\xampp\htdocs>
```

Comment: Is git waiting on some other user input, such as a password?  `set_time_limit()` doesn't help here, as it only is applicable to PHP execution time.

Comment: There isn't a password also updated the post.

Comment: You're running the PHP script from the terminal, yes?  Or, are you running it from the web?  If from the web, I bet your git configuration is dependent on your environment variables, which are different if running from a different user (the web server's user).

Comment: Run it from your terminal.  See if it works there.

Comment: Updated the post. I'm not sure what the 2 warnings are but it does run and complete in the matter of seconds.

Comment: Have you tried using the option `--git-dir="C:\xampp\htdocs"`?

Comment: @DougOwings I get `fatal: C:\Program Files (x86)\git/libexec/git-core\git-pull cannot be used without a working tree.`

Comment: @AdamMerrifield Try `--git-dir="C:\xampp\htdocs\.git" --work-tree="C:\xampp\htdocs"`

Comment: @DougOwings with `--get-dir=` i get `fatal: Not a git repository: ''` but with `--git-dir="C:\xampp\htdocs\.git"` it runs the pull correctly in terminal. It just still doesn't work over the web.

Comment: @DougOwings adding the `--work-tree` works in terminal but still not over web

Comment: @AdamMerrifield Then it does sound like a file permissions issue.

Comment: @DougOwings but all the files are `0777` and i am able to make and delete files using `exec(mkdir test)` & `exec(del test)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `exec`, which waits until the process is finished, use `passthru` and make sure you disabled output buffering. This way you'll immediately see what the problem is.